# Java Spring @GetMapping not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

[I write two functions @GetMapping in one class. Function getProcessImage is working but Function hello is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA0UN.png)

[NOT FOUND 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enquE.png)

I write two functions @GetMapping in one class. Function getProcessImage is working but Function hello is not working. It is not found 404.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{processInsID}/{containerId}")
public ServiceResponse<String> getProcessImage(@PathVariable("processInsID") long procInstId,
                                               @PathVariable("containerId") String containerId) {
    AuthenticationInfo bpmAuthenInfo = new AuthenticationInfo(env.getProperty("jbpm.url"),
            env.getProperty("jbpm.username"), env.getProperty("jbpm.password"), "");
    String result = jbpmService.getImageProcessInProgess(bpmAuthenInfo, containerId, procInstId);
    try {
        return new ServiceResponse<String>(Constant.ServiceResponse.CODE_SUCCESS,
                Constant.ServiceResponse.MSG_SUCCESS, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ServiceResponse<String>(Constant.ServiceResponse.CODE_ERROR, e.getMessage(), null);
    }
}

@GetMapping(value = "/image/")
public ServiceResponse<String> hello() {
    return new ServiceResponse<String>(Constant.ServiceResponse.CODE_ERROR,"okok", null);
}
```

Comment: Please add controller  code to understand your problem

Comment: getProcessImage() is woking good but hello() not found :(

Comment: your hello URL in the browser should be "/image/"  and not "/image"   with a slash

Comment: getProcessImage() url mapping may cause problem for hello() and  add full controller class

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to change your getMapping to /image (i.e remove / ) or you need to add image/ in your url path.I suggest you to remove / in your code as /image